# convert a nsdata into string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdata

I want to convert my saved image in CoreData to String so that I can use it (I don't want to convert it directly into an image as I need to send the image/string to next page too).

Here is my code that I am trying but get **`BAD_EXC_Result`** during run time as it found `nil` value but `tableImageArray[indexPath.row]` has the value as I pass it to `if` statement:

```
if tableImageArray[indexPath.row] != "" {                
    var  _Image:String = String(data: tableImageArray[indexPath.row], encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!   
    //(NSString(data:tableImageArray[indexPath.row], encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as String!
    print(_Image)
}
```

Comment: How did you get the `NSData` in the `tableImageArray`?

Comment: All this doesn't seem to make much sense, If the array holds NSData objects, comparison to String makes no sense. Trying to make a String out of image data makes no sense either. You say the data has UTF8 encoding, but it hasn't - it's image data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my guess.

Judging from the name of the array, `tableImageArray` sounds like an array of images, not strings. So I guess you are trying to convert an image to an `NSData`, and convert that `NSData` to a string.

However, that doesn't work. Just like converting directly from an `UIImage` to a `String` doesn't work.

I guess you have either of these intentions:

1) you want to base64 encode the image to a string. To do this, you just call `base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])` on the data.

2) you want to identify and print a string contained in the `UIImage`. For this you should probably use some OCR libraries. Just Google them!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if let array = tableImageArray {                
    var  _Image:String = String(data: array[indexPath.row], encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!   
    //(NSString(data:array[indexPath.row], encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as String!
    print(_Image)         
}
```

Comment: i m using the same line of code.. entering inside if condition is not my issue. tableimagearray[indexpath.row] has data but when i put        var  _Image:String = String(data: array[indexPath.row], encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!    this line it found nil

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert image data directly to `String` via UTF8 encoding.

The **only** way to convert `NSData` to `String` regardless of the content is base64 encoding.

```
let imageData = tableImageArray[indexPath.row]
let image = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```